# Updating JFrame control with progress of call to another class

Tags: java, jframe

Using NetBeans 8, I have created a JavaFX in Swing Application. The application uses  JFrame and JApplet.

The JFrame has a Label and a button that calls a processing class.  The processing class calls 5 other subclasses.

I would like to have the processing class send status updates to the Label on the JFrame as the class is processing.

I have found that Sockets and ServerSockets can be used to send data from the processing class to the JFrame class but the Label only gets updated when the processing class completes.

There is too much default code to display.

Here is a summary:

> - The JFrame class has the typical main, init, createScene methods.
> - The createScene method creates a GridPane and adds the Label and Button to it, along with an EventHandler for the button.
> - The EventHandler calls the processing class.
> - The processing class simply calls 5 other methods.

I would like to do something like this:

```
public class processingClass {
    public static void process(){
        updateJFrameLabel("About to do something");
        doSomething();
        updateJFrameLabel("status: something Done");
        doSomethingElse();
        updateJFrameLabel("status: something Else Done");
        doMore();
        updateJFrameLabel("more done");
    }
}
```

How can I update the JFrame label real-time as the process is running?

I understand how to use Sockets but I am not sure how to get the Label to update asynchronously.

Any help or a link to information would be helpful.